# Dataflow worker failed to start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job that failed to start the workers with the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 28, in <module>      
from dataflow_worker import batchworker 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 57, in <module> 

from apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.dependency import _dependency_file_copy 
ImportError: No module named dependency
```

However I could run the same job successfully with the exact same code (same setup.py file as well) on another machine, I'm suspecting issues in my configuration of the dataflow project.

Answer (score 0):

If the same job with the exact same code (same setup.py file as well) can run successfully in one cloud project but failed in another project, then there might be an issue with the failed project. The best way to figure out would be to report this as an issue at the public issue tracker per instructions at [Report Bugs and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to have the support from Google to look into the project with you.